# При обновлении страницы пишет "Cannot GET /login" - BrowserRouter от react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Сделал тест роута на реакте:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={()=>{
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>Home page</h1>
                        <Link to="/login">Go to Login</Link>
                    </div>
                );
            }}/>
            <Route path="/login" render={()=>{
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>Login page</h1>
                        <Link to="/">Go to Home</Link>
                    </div>
                );
            }}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("index")
);
```

Все красиво работает если просто запустить. Но получаю сообщение "Cannot GET /login" вместо просмотра страницы Login, если перейти на страницу "/login" просто по адресу (или обновить страницу, находясь на этой странице) после перехода на эту страницу с "Home page".

Нашел [пример работы "BrowserReact"](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvoqvk78), открывал отдельно [решение](https://vvoqvk78.codesandbox.io/), и там все нормально работает.

На более старой версии реакта и роутера решал вопрос расположением компиленных js по нужным адресам.

Это нормальное поведение BrowserRouter? Или я что-то недопонимаю, ведь найденный мной пример работает корректно?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `exact` с `login`

Comment: @Puvvl , да я там тестил и с exact и без, разницы не было, все равно при обновлении страницы пишет не то, что ожидается :( вот главная без exact нормально не работает.

Comment: а обернуть 2 `Route` в `<div></div>` после `<Switch>`

Comment: @Puvvl , а смысл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, вероятнее всего, в сервере webpack-dev-sever.

На удивление проблема решилась на другом сервере (от create-react-app `react-scripts start`). Но опять же, решение сработало только после того, как я полностью удалил node&npm, а так же установленные зависимости, и снова установил их. До полного удаления node&npm по какой-то причине этот сервер работать не хотел.

Answer (score 2):

Может, кому-то поможет: мне помогло добавление следющего кода в webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю как памятку себе. Та же проблема webpack4 
Решилось добавлением строки publicPath: '/', в webpack.config.js

---

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(paths.SRC, 'index.jsx'),
  output: {
    path: paths.DIST,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы работаете на своей сборке не забудьте в Webpack.config прописать:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло заменить BrowserRouter на HashRouter

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал сборку на Webpack и при попытке настроить роутинг (когда вводишь ссылку в адресной строке в ручную - выскакивала ошибка

`devServer: {  port: 8000, open: true, historyApiFallback: true, }`

мне помог этот вариан. Спасибо парню который подсказыл выше в коментах